# How could I output colored print statements in the console in Eclipse with java?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I already tried a seperate way as shown in what I tried, but it didnt output correctly.

```
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
```

After setting up the strings I tried to run it with this line:

```
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "Connect 4:" + ANSI_RESET);
```

And the output was :

```
[31mConnect 4:[0m
```

How could I do this correctly?

Comment: Could you clarify your question. it appears that code is running fine and it is giving expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In recent versions of Eclipse you can enable ANSI codes in the Preferences > Run/Debug > Console > ANSI Support